# Option CSS does not work on Chrome

Tags: css

This code works fine for Mozilla but not for Chrome

```
option:checked { 
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #043A4D inset;
}
```

Comment: Did your problem solved??

Answer (score 1):

If you wants to more `vendor-specific` then use this

```
option:checked {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px!important;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px!important;
  border-radius: 5px!important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #043A4D inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #043A4D inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #043A4D inset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you are referring to the outline that appears when an element is in focus. If so try removing that in css with

```
option:focus, option:active {
    outline: none;
}
```

However you should replace it with something as it's aids visibility of selected elements and also helps with keyboard navigation.

If this isn't the problem could you please provide a screenshot showing the problem.

Some examples of [outline usage on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/outline/)